# Pyspark - Pivot function issue

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pivot

Input should be as below:

| company | sales |
| --- | --- |
| amazon | 100 |
| flipkart | 900 |
| ebay | 890 |
| amazon | 100 |
| flipkart | 100 |
| ebay | 10 |
| amazon | 100 |
| flipkart | 90 |
| ebay | 10 |

And expected output should be as below:

| amazon | flipkart | ebay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 300 | 1090 | 910 |

Tried using pivot function, but its not working. Any help on this would be appreciated.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you have any existing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use groupBy() and first() function.

```
data = [("amazon", 100), ("flipkart", 300), ("amazon", 50), ("ebay", 50), ("ebay", 150), ("amazon", 300)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data,["company","sales"])
df.show()
+--------+-----+
| company|sales|
+--------+-----+
|  amazon|  100|
|flipkart|  300|
|  amazon|   50|
|    ebay|   50|
|    ebay|  150|
|  amazon|  300|
+--------+-----+

df.groupBy("company").agg(sum("sales").alias("sales"))\
.groupBy().pivot("company").agg(first("sales")).show()


+------+----+--------+
|amazon|ebay|flipkart|
+------+----+--------+
|   450| 200|     300|
+------+----+--------+
```

Thanks to @andy, for the helper column solution

```
df.groupBy(lit(0).alias("Key")).pivot("company")\
.agg(sum("sales").alias("sales")).show()

+---+------+----+--------+
|Key|amazon|ebay|flipkart|
+---+------+----+--------+
|  0|   450| 200|     300|
+---+------+----+--------+
```

The key column can be removed using drop() function

```
df.groupBy(lit(0).alias("Key")).pivot("company")\
.agg(sum("sales").alias("sales")).drop("key").show()
+------+----+--------+
|amazon|ebay|flipkart|
+------+----+--------+
|   450| 200|     300|
+------+----+--------+
```

Comment: @andy.. yes thats a nice idea..I'll add it to answer

Answer (score 2):

I've been using the following test dataset to compose this solution:

```py
data = [("amazon", 100), ("flipkart", 300), ("amazon", 50), ("ebay", 50), ("ebay", 150), ("amazon", 300)]
columns= ["company", "sales"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)
```

This will result in the following dataframe:

```
+--------+-----+
|company |sales|
+--------+-----+
|amazon  |100  |
|flipkart|300  |
|amazon  |50   |
|ebay    |50   |
|ebay    |150  |
|amazon  |300  |
+--------+-----+
```

For your specific wide table I would do the following:

```py
df \
  .groupBy("company") \
  .pivot("company") \
  .sum("sales")
```

Spark will save keep the null values. The function `pivot` is really expensive on its own.

To really get your result you can do the following for removing the `null` values by grouping and summing again.

```py
companies = list(
    df.select('company').toPandas()['company'].unique()
)
pdf = df \
  .groupBy("company") \
  .pivot("company") \
  .sum("sales") \
  .groupBy() \
  .agg(*[F.sum(c).alias(c) for c in companies])
```

Result is:

```
+------+--------+----+
|amazon|flipkart|ebay|
+------+--------+----+
|   450|     300| 200|
+------+--------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot()` function as shown in other answers.

Here is the shorter version of `groupBy()` and `pivot()` combination.

```
>>> data = [("amazon", 100), ("flipkart", 300), ("amazon", 50), ("ebay", 50), ("ebay", 150), ("amazon", 300)]
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data,["company","sales"])
>>> df.groupBy().pivot('company').sum('sales').show()
+------+----+--------+
|amazon|ebay|flipkart|
+------+----+--------+
|   450| 200|     300|
+------+----+--------+
```